# java read all files in a folder to attache in email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have javax utility to send email with attachments , for attachment i have to mention exact file path to send in email like if i have 10 files in a folder then i have to point the 10 exact paths separated by \\ and then i will be able to send email , my requirement is the i want to just point the start or ending string that a file contain and program should select all files in a folder containing mentioned string and attache to email.For example there are two files in folder names `"xyz_100.pdf"` and `"abc_100.pdf"` so in that case i want to decide path for attachment like this *100*.pdf and email programm should pick these both files , below is my current code for considering attachments

```
if (null != Attachments) {
                    int StartIndex = 0, PosIndex = 0;
                    while (-1 != (PosIndex = Attachments.indexOf("///", StartIndex))) {
                        // Create and fill other message parts;
                        MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
                        FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(Attachments.substring(StartIndex, PosIndex));
                        mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                        mbp.setFileName(fds.getName());
                        mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
                        PosIndex += 3;
                        StartIndex = PosIndex;
                    }
                    // Last, or only, attachment file
                    if (StartIndex < Attachments.length()) {
                        MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
                        FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(Attachments.substring(StartIndex));
                        mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                        mbp.setFileName(fds.getName());
                        mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
                    }
                }
```

While Attachments is exact path to a file in folder

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways in Java to scan a directory to discover all the files, and to match files against a pattern or base string.  A simple place to start is the [java.io.File list method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list--) (and related methods).

Once you have an array of file names or File objects, you can iterate over that array and add each as an attachment:

```
for (file : files) {
    MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
    mbp.attachFile(file);
    mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
}
```

Comment: how can i update my current code ? please give example

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm not going to write the code for you.  Make some effort and if you can't get it to work post what you've tried.